# Can't update profilePhoto with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm able to retrieve profile photos just fine, but run into ErrorAccessDenied when trying to update photos. According to this:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update

The User.ReadWrite permission should be sufficient. I have assigned my application this privilege using manage.windowsazure.com (and also tried granting all kinds of other privileges), but still get the error. Here's the current set of privileges I've granted to the app:

`Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All MailboxSettings.ReadWrite offline_access profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All`

I'm obtaining the Bearer token with the client_credentials flow as follows:

```
curl -d grant_type=client_credentials \
     -d client_id=CLIENT_ID \
     -d client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
     -d resource=https://graph.microsoft.com \
     https://login.microsoftonline.com/DOMAINNAME/oauth2/token
```

I then try to update the profile photo like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer BEARERTOKEN" \
     --request PATCH \
     -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
     -d @photo.jpg
     https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERPRINCIPALNAME/photo/\$value
```

And I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "REQUESTID",
      "date": "2016-05-23T16:42:21"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you listed *delegated* permissions configured for your app, but retrieved the token using the client credentials flow, which uses separate *application* permissions. As per the documentation page that you referenced the scope required to update user profile photo is User.ReadWrite. This can't be done with the app-only scopes, including User.ReadWrite.All. User photo can be updated using the Authorization Code Grant Flow (see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization)

Comment: Sorry about the User.ReadWrite.All vs User.ReadWrite confusion, I've corrected my post.

Can you point me to where it says the profile Photo can't be updated with app-only scopes? If that's the case, then that really throws a wrench into the works. This application needs to be able to update people's photos as a standalone process, without end-user interaction through authorization codes or anything like that.

The background for this is that the AAD sync process doesn't seem to reliably update photos for users, so we're trying to setup a separate process to do that.

Comment: Ohh, now I think I get it. User.ReadWrite is a delegated permission, not an application permission. And it is the only allowed scope that is documented on that page above for updating photos.

What was confusing was that I could *read* photos just fine. But the reason for that is because the GET method *also* supports application permission scopes such as User.ReadWrite.All. (And those are documented on the corresponding page).

Looks like I'll have to rethink this whole approach.