# How to change an Office 365 user avatar with Azure SDK for Python

Tags: python, azure, sdk, avatar

I've successfully been using [this](https://github.com/sfonteneau/script_modify_password_googleapps_and_office365) script to sync passwords for users on our local Samba server and our Office 365. The script uses [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python).
I would also like to update the user image/avatar for the users in Office 365 with some script that doesn't need a windows host (like powershell with 365-modules seems to do) but I'm having a hard time navigating the documentation for [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python).

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 is not Azure, so you won't find anything for that in this repo (I own that repo, so I know it :)).

However, in my understanding this is perflectly doable with Microsoft Graph
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/python

There is a sample called:

> profile_photo() returns the user's profile photo and optionally saves a copy to a local file.

which probably gives a good idea of the API (even if it's not a write sample as you need).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I think I've tried the graph api in the past but didn't understand one main point, the auth using sign in via web seems strange to me, I want to run these scripts commandline and not have to re-auth every now and then.

Comment: Wow, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396426/cant-update-profilephoto-with-microsoft-graph-api) and [Note To update the photo of any user in the organization, your app must have the User.ReadWrite.All application permission and call this API under its own identity, not on behalf of a user.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update) it's not possible to update a user photo as admin without the user signing in?? Or am I misunderstanding?